# Can Matter/Thread devices be controlled directly from Android app?

Tags: android-sdk-tools, google-home, google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

I know the [official doc](https://developers.home.google.com/samples/matter-app) says a Google Nest Hub is needed to control Matter device from a ["Google Home" like app](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/matter-sample-app) using [Google Home Mobile SDK](https://developers.home.google.com/matter/apis/home).

Is it possible to control a Matter/Thread device from an Android app without a `Google Nest Hub`?

If not, is there any plan from Google to add `Matter API` to the `Android SDK` allowing apps controlling Matter/Thread devices natively ?

EDIT:
There is a sample app for controlling Matter devices:
https://github.com/google-home/sample-app-for-matter-android/

You can check wether your mobile device has the required services for Matter here:
https://developers.home.google.com/matter/verify-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I used https://github.com/google-home/sample-app-for-matter-android

worked like a charm for a simple product. Doesn't work for more complicated product, but I guess it can be extended.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The sample app requires Google Services services version 22.30 or higher. Do you know if Google has any plan to ship the Matter services natively in futures versions of Android ?

Comment: I would assume so, I think Google is heavily invested in Matter. However, I remember so many products that Google shut down in the past that I would not put my money on it ;)

Comment: Do you confirm that you can control a Matter Thread (i.e. not Matter Wifi)  device from your Android app without Hub ?

Comment: You cannot, as you need a thread border router.

Comment: To clarify: some WiFi routers can act as thread border routers. In this case, Android should work without a hub.